# Can I @override the following @overloaded Python function?

Tags: python, overriding, overloading, mypy, typing

The PySide6 function `QComboBox.addItem` is type-hinted, in `QtWidgets.pyi`, like this:

```py
@overload
def addItem(self, icon: Union[PySide6.QtGui.QIcon, PySide6.QtGui.QPixmap], text: str, userData: Any = ...) -> None: ...
@overload
def addItem(self, text: str, userData: Any = ...) -> None: ...
```

In order to cleanly (according to type checkers) `@override` it, I need to provide a Python implementation which "accepts all possible arguments of" signatures 1 and 2, yet I seem unable to do so not least due to the fact that the `text` argument appears in different positions.

What are strategies to deal with this?

Comment: I'm not well enough versed in MyPy etc. to answer this properly, as I personally don't find this sort of  type annotation useful. But did you try offering a separate `@override` for each `@overload`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that is a neat idea, but I still need an implementation. I have since found that `addItem(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:` works for typing, but requires a lot of additional work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but `@override` should only need to be added on the **implementation**, not the `@overload`s.

```py
import typing_extensions as typing

import PyQt5.QtGui
import PyQt5.QtWidgets

class MyQComboBox(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QComboBox):

    @typing.overload
    def addItem(self, text: str, userData: typing.Any = ...) -> None: ...

    @typing.overload
    def addItem(self, icon: PyQt5.QtGui.QIcon, text: str, userData: typing.Any = ...) -> None: ...

    @typing.override
    def addItem(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> None:
        """
        Your implementation. `*args` and `**kwargs` are just
        placeholders for the signature you actually want.
        """
```

```
$ mypy test.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

For mypy to stop complaining about overridden `@overload`ed methods in a subclass you need to copy all overloads over (as with the example above). This is unergonomic and error-prone. In my opinion, you should just implement the signature(s) *you* want to accept for the overridden method in the subclass, and suppress warnings for `@overload` issues with `# type: ignore`.